# Emacs Terminal.app Meta Key - German MacBook Keyboard

Tags: macos, unix, emacs, terminal

Good evening,

I have a problem using Emacs in Terminal.app the last 9 hours but wasn't able to solve it on my own.
The workarounds I have found on Stackoverflow etc. didn't persuade me.

I didn't want to use the Option 'Wahltaste als Metataste verwenden' (alt/option as meta), because I have to type for example {}[] with my alt-key. Keybinding of these Charakters in Emacs is no solution for me, because outside of Emacs in nano I want to use []{}..., too.

I also didn't want to use iTerm2.app, I think it should be possible in Terminal too.
Because sometimes I use Emacs over SSH, it is not possible to choose an GUI-based Emacs either.
A possibilty I would accept is to use the left alt/option key for meta and the right one for typing []{}... Or the Fn-Key for meta... 
But I wasn't able to do it the last 9 hours...

I already ported 'emulate-mac-keybord-mode.el' from Aquamacs, but I didn't get it work as expected.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance,

Zappel

Comment: You are aware of Tramp, aren't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on a TTY Emacs within Terminal.app, you *may probably* have some success with kernel level remappings of modifier keys, using [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/).  I do not know, because I never used it for such things, and since the key codes, Terminal.app sends to the TTY process when a modifier is pressed, are ultimately hard-coded in Terminal.app, this is neither easy nor particularly pretty.

iTerm2 probably provides means to customize modifiers individually, and is generally a superior terminal emulator (with the notable exception of color management), but frankly, do yourself a favor, and use a GUI Emacs.

A GUI Emacs provides a much nicer expierence on OS X.  You are not only able to map each modifier key individually with `mac-option-modifier` and friends, you also more modifiers available, namely Super and Hyper.

For instance, the following setting uses the Command keys as Meta, the function key has Hyper, and keeps the Option keys for OS X, so that you can still use the alternate layout level:

```lisp
(setq mac-option-modifier   'none
      mac-command-modifier  'meta
      mac-function-modifier 'hyper)
```

To edit files on remote systems, you'd just use Tramp then.

Comment: Okay, I didn't mention, that I already tried KeyRemap4MacBook, but it's not really pretty. But Tramp is a very good hint, thank you! I think GUI Emacs will be my choice, even if I'm not 100% persuaded. It is annoying to switch the window every time I started Emacs out of Terminal.app..

Comment: @Zappel It's likely your only option…  if you don't want to use prettier tools (e.g. iTerm2, or a GUI Emacs), you have to live with the ugly things.

Comment: Well, I'm using GUI Emacs now, and the ugly thing is caused especially by using GUI Emacs. I know that my english is not so good, and I'll prefer to write in good old german, but I think this is the wrong place to do so... So i'll give another try: When I'm navigating, copying, moving etc. some files in my Terminal.app and want to edit some files, I start the Emacs GUI App out of the Command Line, but the 'focus' won't change automatically to the new window, but will still remain in the Terminal.app. So for short editing I will use nano further, because I have no 'focusing'-problems there.

Comment: @Zappel We can have a chat in German, if you wish.  I agree, though, that this is not the proper place, so please feel free to write me a mail at lunaryorn@gmail.com :)